# Counting erythrocytes

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

I'm trying to count the number of erythrocytes on a microscope image. These are the smaller cells. (I've tried first using CNN and sliding window, but it was too slow, so I'm looking for a simplier segmentation)

My approach is:

1. threshold
2. find and draw all contours filled so that the cells won't have holes,
3. make distance transform
4. iterating over all maxima
5. masking out a current maximum with a circle having the radius of the maximum and storing the maximum position

My problem is, some cells have a "hole" in the middle - bright area similar by the value to background. If I threshold the image, some of the cell-masks become not a circle but a half circle, with the distance-transform values far below expected value.

I've marked the cells having the "holes" on the mask image.

Hov could I close the hole or the circle? Is there a threshold method or trick?

Below is the part of code responsible for cell extraction:

```
cv::adaptiveThreshold(_imgIn ,th, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, (bgblack ? CV_THRESH_BINARY: CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV), 35, 5 );//| CV_THRESH_OTSU);
                Mat kernel1 = Mat::ones(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
                for (int i=0; i< 5;i++)
                {
                    dilate(th, th, kernel1);
                    erode(th, th, kernel1);
                }
                vector<vector<Point> > contours;        

                findContours(th, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);   

                mask = 0;
                for( unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
                { 
                    drawContours(mask, contours, i, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
                }


                cv::distanceTransform(mask, dist, CV_DIST_L2, 3);           
            }



            double min, max;
            cv::Point pmax;
            Mat tmp1 = dist.clone();
            while (true)
            {
                cv::minMaxLoc(tmp1, 0, &max, 0, &pmax);
                if ( max < 5 ) 
                    break;
                cv::circle(_imgIn, pmax, 3 , cv::Scalar(0), CV_FILLED );
                cv::circle(tmp1, pmax, max , cv::Scalar(0), CV_FILLED );

            }
```

[image: Detected]
[image: Mask]
[image: Origin]

Comment: Is the bottom of these three images your original image?

Comment: As a side note: The cells with holes represent an under-count. Yet, you don't seem too concerned about the possibility of overcounting (there are several cases where your algorithm finds three cells where I might have interpreted two). It might be good to reflect on what you're trying to do and what the bounds on your error need to be to accomplish it. It may be that it's either impossible or that you're already there. If this isn't the case, I'd worry that you're about to enter a maze of tweaks that, in the end, still won't provide the accuracy you want.

Comment: @Richard yes, the bottom one is the original. However not my, just one example image.

Comment: Are you able to speak to my second question at all? If you're able to assess your current accuracy versus your needs, you may already have a sufficient solution.

Comment: @Richard First of all, thank you very much for your observation and suggestions. My solution is not sufficient. In fact, the image in example is of a very good quality. On other images I lose much more cells. I hoped this is a very common and known problem and a solution is in parametrising adaptive threshold algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Closing holes**
[Closing](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/close.htm) is an important operator from the field of mathematical morphology. Like its dual operator opening, it can be derived from the fundamental operations of erosion and dilation. Like those operators it is normally applied to binary images, although there are graylevel versions. Closing is similar in some ways to dilation in that it tends to enlarge the boundaries of foreground (bright) regions in an image (and shrink background color holes in such regions), but it is less destructive of the original boundary shape. As with other morphological operators, the exact operation is determined by a structuring element. The effect of the operator is to preserve background regions that have a similar shape to this structuring element, or that can completely contain the structuring element, while eliminating all other regions of background pixels.

**In Open CV this looks as follows**

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('j.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

closing = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[image: Closing example]

Full documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html).